# PlannerTaskDetail's GetETag returns null. If-Match header not working

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, dotnet-sdk

I'm trying to update task details:

```js
var t = await graphClient.Planner.Tasks[task.Id].Details.Request().GetAsync();

var ETag = t.GetETag();
```

However `GetETag()` returns `null`.

The ETag is part of the AdditionalData dictionary, so I can extract it writing my own method.

For example:

```js
var e = etag = (taskDetails.AdditionalData["@odata.etag"] as JsonElement?)?.GetString();
```

But why does the built-in method not work? My code is almost exactly the same as Microsoft's [test code](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/tests/Microsoft.Graph.DotnetCore.Test/Requests/Functional/PlannerTests.cs).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please debug and check GetEtag() method that is exposed [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/4dd7864ff32ae736b5cfc5419a1c6e478ef0c487/src/Microsoft.Graph/Requests/Helpers/EtagHelper.cs#L24). Also validate the entity passed onto this method is not null.

```
namespace Microsoft.Graph
{
    using System;

    /// <summary>
    /// Helper class to extract @odata.etag property and to specify If-Match headers for requests.
    /// </summary>
    public static class EtagHelper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Name of the OData etag property.
        /// </summary>
        public const string ODataEtagPropertyName = "@odata.etag";

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the etag of an entity.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="entity">The entity that contains an etag.</param>
        /// <returns>Etag value if present, null otherwise.</returns>
        public static string GetEtag(this Entity entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));
            }

            entity.AdditionalData.TryGetValue(ODataEtagPropertyName, out object etag);
            return etag as string;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I directly used the method and it still doesn't work. `return etag as string` is null because etag is JsonElement, not string. Same reason why for my code I had to use `(taskDetails.AdditionalData["@odata.etag"] as JsonElement?)?.GetString()`

Comment: I should also mention that `object as string` used to work on Microsoft.Graph 3.8 but after upgrading to 4.x I've had to use `object as JsonElement`